# MAX3232 ESE+ Not Working but ST3232C and MAX3232 Working on same PCB

Tags: esp32, rs232, ttl, overheat, max3232

[image]

I have designed a pcb for Rs232 to TTL, UART converter for using ESP32. I will control an LCD with ESP32. Some IC's (MAX3232 ESE+) heating at the first start. and not working just heating and heating. Sometimes working properly but some times not working. Another ICs such as ST3232C and MAX3232 everytime working I have test at all situations and working there is no heating.

what is the main differences those ICs I didnt find any differences on datasheet.Which ICs would you recommend I use?

this is my schematic:

[image]
[image]

I have tested 4.7k and 10k pull rezistor but there is no change.
I am using 0.1uf for all capacitor

Comment: `Which ICs would you recommend I use?`.. asking for recommendations is off topic here ... just use whichever works for you ... perhaps you could ask about the overheating IC instead, because it may be an indication of a design flaw

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the wrong ICs, you have the wrong circuit.

It likely is a pure coincident that the two types work and the third type does not.

The circuit has a design flaw that explains this. The CMOS/TTL inputs have no pull resistors, and contrary to MAX232, the MAX3232 does not have built-in pull-up resistors so they are floating.

Also most of the electrolytic capacitors in the schematic are connected with wrong polarity, but 0.1uF capacitors are rarely polarized or electrolytic. The photos seem to show non-polarized ceramic caps. Only you know if the schematics do not match what you built.

The capacitor values are correct only for 3.3V voltage, not for 3.0V - 5.5V.

Also the pull-up on output is useless as it's always an output. The input can benefit from pull-up only if it is driven by e.g. MCU which does not drive the pin until the software configures the pin as output.